# Example of an infinite number of vectors in general position in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

We say that a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are in general position if any $n$ of them are linearly indpendent. I am looking for an explicit construction of an infinite set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in general position that can be (relatively) easily proved to be so. By 'explicit' I mean in particular that I would like to avoid any application of the Axiom of Choice. So an answer such as "delete all vectors contained in hyperplanes spanned by any $n-1$ of the previously chosen vectors, then pick a vector from the remainder and repeat" is not acceptable.

For $n = 2$, I came up with the following pretty simple construction. For simplicity, let us identify $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the set of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ in the usual way. Let $\alpha$ be an irrational number, say $\alpha = \sqrt{2}$. Consider the following set of points on the unit circle:
$$
S = \{e^{i2\pi \alpha k } \colon k \in \mathbb{Z} \}.
$$
Since these are all points on the unit circle, the only way for them not to be in general position is if two are the same or if one is the negative of the other. Suppose the later (the proof in the former case is similar). Then, for some distinct integers $k_1$ and $k_2$, we have
$$
e^{i2\pi \alpha k_1} = - e^{i2\pi \alpha k_2} = e^{i\pi} e^{i2\pi \alpha k_2} = e^{i2\pi (\alpha k_2 + 1/2)}. 
$$
Thus $e^{i2\pi (\alpha(k_1 - k_2) -1/2)} = 0$ which implies that $\alpha(k_1 - k_2) -1/2$ is an integer, a contradiction to the irrationality of $\alpha$.

Is there an easy way to generalise this argument to higher dimensions (with a relatively easy proof)? Or is there some other easy construction?

Comment: @NoahSchweber All such vectors are multiples of $(\sqrt{p_m})_{1 \leq m\leq k}$. Perhaps you meant something like $\{(\sqrt{p_m})_{1+n \leq m \leq k+m}:n \in \Bbb N\}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an easy enough construction of uncountably many such vectors. For $x \in \Bbb R$, define $v_x \in \Bbb R^n$ to be
$$
v_x = (1,x,x^2,\dots,x^{n-1}).
$$
Any $n$ (distinct) such vectors are linearly independent. To see that this is the case, it suffices to note that for any $x_1,\dots,x_n$, the matrix whose rows are $v_{x_1},\dots,v_{x_n}$ is a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) with distinct rows and is therefore invertible.

Comment: What a beautiful answer! Thanks so much!